# Swift3でのエラーCannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer<xmlChar>'

Tags: swift, swift3, swift2

Swift2からSwift3へのConvertを行なったところ、以下のエラーが出て解決できません。

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer<xmlChar>' (aka 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>') to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<_>'
```

該当コードは以下の通りです。`String(cString: UnsafePointer<CChar>(char!))`のところでエラーが出ます。

```
static func fromXmlChar(_ char: UnsafePointer<xmlChar>?) -> String? {
    if char != nil {
        return String(cString: UnsafePointer<CChar>(char!))
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift3コンパイラを搭載したバージョンのXcodeは、かなり昔に捨ててしまったので、Xcode 9.4.1のSwift 3.3モードでテストしただけですが、Swift 3では、2種類の`String.init(cString:)`が定義されていたはずですので、不要なポインタ変換(Swift 3ではご質問に記載`UnsafePointer<CChar>(...)`のようなイニシャライザ構文では、ポインタ型間の変換はできなくなりました)を削除してやれば、コンパイルは通るはずです。

[`init(cString: UnsafePointer<CChar>)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1641523-init) <- 今のあなたのコードが使っている方

[`init(cString: UnsafePointer<UInt8>)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2430308-init) <- こっちなら変換せずに使える

```
    static func fromXmlChar(_ char: UnsafePointer<xmlChar>?) -> String? {
        if char != nil {
            return String(cString: char!) //<- 変換せずに直接`UnsafePointer<xmlChar>`を渡す
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

あるいは、条件付きバインディングを使った方がよりSwiftっぽくなります。

```
    static func fromXmlChar(_ char: UnsafePointer<xmlChar>?) -> String? {
        if let cStr = char {
            return String(cString: cStr)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

今後、Swift 4, Swift 5への変換をすぐに行われるかどうかわかりませんが、あちこちを可能な限りSwiftっぽく書いておいた方が、変換に成功する確率が高くなる傾向があります。

なお、Swift 3コンパイラではコンパイルできないコードでもSwift 4コンパイラのSwift 3.3モードではコンパイル出来てしまう場合があります。上記のコードがあなたのお手持ちのXcodeでコンパイルできない場合は、お知らせ下さい。